# Issues with the Perl binding of the Rackspace Cloud API and setting/getting object metadata

Tags: perl, api, file, rackspace-cloud

Using the unofficial [Perl binding of the Rackspace Cloud API](http://search.cpan.org/~ckras/WebService-Rackspace-CloudFiles-1.04/lib/WebService/Rackspace/CloudFiles.pm) [[Github](https://github.com/Htbaa/WebService-Rackspace-CloudFiles)], I can't for the life of me set or retrieve the metadata of a given object.

I can successfully pull files down from the cloud, but when I call `object_metadata` as defined in the documentation I get an error complaining about `uninitialized value`. I can verify through the Cloud Files manager that a value is set for `Status` in the metadata. I've even tried checking for `X-Object-Meta-Status` (with no success).

Relevant code is as follows:

```
# authentication
# set $container to pre-made container
my @files = $container->objects(prefix => 'tainted/')->all;
FILE: foreach my $file(@files) {

  # throws undefined // have tried capitalized and not, quotes and none
  next FILE if $file->object_metadata->{'status'} != '-1';

  # download file from object & do stuff with it

  # does not update object in cloud (not sure if anything id done locally)
  $file->object_metadata({ status => $status });

}
```

Like I said, objects are successfully being retrieved, I just am not able to view meta on a given file. I've played with some variations of what is above, but each test of a new approach costs bandwidth (money!). Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What's actually in the metadata? Try using [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dumper) to inspect the structure of `$file->object_metadata`.

Comment: `print Dumper($file->object_metadata);` outputs `$VAR1 = {};` for each $file.

Comment: I went to the Rackspace website and opened a chat window to a sales guy. He is offering me a 20 GBP credit free trial account that can be used as a sandbox. I have no idea how much service that gives you, but I suggest you do the same.

Comment: Thanks so much, @simbabque! That is extremely helpful. I'll see what they can do for me.

Comment: Here's a link: http://www.rackspace.co.uk/legal/promotions/november-promotion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the feeling that the metadata is not being set at all. Let's take a look at [WebService::Rackspace::CloudFiles::Object](https://github.com/Htbaa/WebService-Rackspace-CloudFiles/blob/master/lib/WebService/Rackspace/CloudFiles/Object.pm#L42), which is built using Moose:

```
has 'object_metadata' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'HashRef',
    required => 0,
    default => sub {
        return {};
    }
);
```

So there's an optional property `object_metadata`, which can be retrieved using the built-in selector. Great!

The objects that are being returned by `$container->objects` are created in [WebService::Rackspace::CloudFiles::Container](https://github.com/Htbaa/WebService-Rackspace-CloudFiles/blob/master/lib/WebService/Rackspace/CloudFiles/Container.pm#L143) like this (snipped):

```
foreach my $bit (@bits) {
  push @objects,
    WebService::Rackspace::CloudFiles::Object->new(
    cloudfiles => $self->cloudfiles,
    container => $self,
    name => $bit->{name},
    etag => $bit->{hash},
    size => $bit->{bytes},
    content_type => $bit->{content_type},
    last_modified => $bit->{last_modified},
  );
}
```

So if I see this correctly, there's no `object_metadata` property in this call, which is fine because it's optional. But if it's not set, it makes sense that you retrieve an empty hashref, doesn't it?

I'd say you might want to patch that in yourself. :-/

---

I did a little more digging: In the [CloudFiles docs](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Retrieve_Object-d1e1856.html) it says that the metadata is returned in the HTTP header of the result. The [docs on how to retrieve metadata](http://docs.rackspace.com/files/api/v1/cf-devguide/content/Retrieve_Object_Metadata-d1e2301.html) on its own gives a good explanation of how it is transmitted. But unfortunately, there is no parsing going on for that in the module for sure.

Comment: Actually, was just digging a little deeper, and I think that the existing code does actually handle headers (or at least it should). [See here.](https://github.com/Htbaa/WebService-Rackspace-CloudFiles/blob/master/lib/WebService/Rackspace/CloudFiles/Object.pm#L316)

Comment: @Dan: I think it does, but not in the case you described in your question. At least I think so. Cannot really test it. The `_set_attributes_from_response` is called from `get`, `head` and `get_filename` in `Object`, which makes sense. But if I see this right, then the `object` method in `Container` never calls any of these methods. It just creates one `Object` for each of the `$bit`s it gets back in that callback. I cannot test it, but to me it looks like the metadata is only set if you request one file specifically.

Comment: I see what you're saying now. That seems reasonable.